# Is calling oDataModel method "create"/"update" possible with more than one record?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sapui5

I'm afraid this is a very simple question. It might be too easy to be asked here, but I can't figure this out on my own and I just want to know.

It is about oDataModel and the methods "create" and "update".
In Demo Kit I find the interface as follows:

create(sPath, oData, mParameters?) : object

update(sPath, oData, mParameters?) : object

The description of "oData" says in both methods "Data of the entry that should be created/updated."

So I understand that oData is exactly one data record. And in SAP in the corresponding method (e.g. StorageUnitSet_Update_Entity) I can read this single record with the method in ABAP:

```
CALL METHOD io_data_provider->read_entry_data
  IMPORTING
    es_data = ls_data.
```

Is there a common way to pass more than one record?

In my case I have a simple table with only one column containing storage units. By pressing "save" those shall be created in backend system. Now I am not sure if I loop my table and pass every single storage unit and call this "create method" for each entry. Or I could write all storage units into a long string and pass this one string just once. But if there is a "more correct" way to handle this, I would love to know it.

Here is a little bit code. I tried to minimize it to the necessary:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "xxx/namespace/controller/BaseController",
    "sap/ui/model/resource/ResourceModel",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "sap/ui/core/ValueState"
], function (BaseController, ResourceModel, JSONModel, ValueState) {
    "use strict";

    return BaseController.extend("xxx.namespace.controller.iPunkt01", {

        onInit: function () {

            
            this._data = {
                LePool: [ {lenum: "123456"},
                    {lenum: "234567"},
                    {lenum: "234567"}
                    ]
            };

            this.jModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            this.jModel.setData(this._data);

            // bind table
            this.byId("ins").setModel(this.jModel);

        },
        
        onStartVert: function () {
            // call oData Method create 
            
        },
    });
});
```

And here is the XML:

```
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:f="sap.f" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    controllerName="xxx.namespace.controller.iPunkt01" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="iPunkt01">
    <App>
        <pages>
            <Page title="i - Punkt">
                <content>
                    <Label text="Lagereinheit" labelFor="lenum"/>
                    <Input id="lenum" editable="true" submit="onSubmit"/>
                    <Table id="ins" items="{/LePool}">
                        <columns>
                            <Column width="50px"/>
                            <Column>
                                <Text text="LE Pool"/>
                            </Column>
                        </columns>
                        <items>
                            <ColumnListItem>
                                <cells>
                                    <Button icon="sap-icon://delete" press="onDeleteRow" type="Reject"/>
                                    <Text id="lenumCell" text="{lenum}"/>
                                </cells>
                            </ColumnListItem>
                        </items>
                    </Table>
                    <l:HorizontalLayout>
                        <Button text="Zurück" icon="sap-icon://nav-back" press="onNavBack"/>
                        <Button text="Start Verteilung" icon="sap-icon://share-2" press="onStartVert"/>
                    </l:HorizontalLayout>
                </content>
            </Page>
        </pages>
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you could work with batch. In the Backend tho every Request will be handled on it's own.

Here are some Tutorials how to pass multiple Requests:

- [Batch Request](https://mrnajzs-sapui5.blogspot.com/2020/06/batch-request.html)
- [Batch Request](https://blogs.sap.com/2012/11/18/gateway-batch-calls-from-sapui5/)

If you want to access all Data at the same Time in the Backend you could work with an **[DEEP_INSERT](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_hba/1.0/en-US/63/b45e1756d94c748affe4282fd3ff55/content.htm?no_cache=true) **.

- [DEEP_INSERT Tutorial](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/08/30/sap-gateway-deep-insert-end-to-end-scenario/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check this.

Comment: Thank, I chose the batch version :) is it not possible to debug in ABAP when running the method "SubmitChanges" in batch request? I cannot even debug the success and error events in WebIDE after "SubmitChanges" ran. Is this correct or am I doing something wrong?